# Error Encountered: Macro Argument Missing

Tags: google-apps-script

I am generating google docs and then trying to change the address of an anchor so that it points to that document

When I click on the link it throws this error Error Encountered: Macro Argument Missing
However it still opens the correct page in a new tab
The anchor is created in the UIbuilder and changed with the following code

```
 var newid= createPersonal(ename, reportPeriod);
var link= 'https://docs.google.com/a/meditech.com/document/d/'+newid+'/edit'
var anc=app.getElementById("Anchor1").setHref(link);
```

I tried manually adding an anchor and it does not throw the error. However, it places the link at the bottom of the page and not where I specified it to go

```
var anchor = app.createAnchor("report", link);
anchor.setStyleAttributes({LEFT: '385px'}).setStyleAttributes({TOP: '235px'});
```

Comment: The [UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/) was deprecated on Dec 2014.

Answer (score 0):

From seeing the above code, it looks like the error is genarted in some other part of the code, not by the code you shared.

I am not sure why you are building the link manually when it is available through DocsList services when you have ID of Document

```
var newId = 'ID_OF_YOUR_DOC';
var link = DocsList.getFileById(newId).getUrl();
var anc = app.getElementById("Anchor1").setHref(link);
```

To have a fixed position with respect to the screen, you need to set position attribute.
eg.

```
var anchor = app.createAnchor("report", link);
anchorAttributes = {
  'position' : 'fixed',
  'left' : '100',
  'top' : '100'
};
anchor.setStyleAttributes(anchorAttributes);
```